# How to select a specific element when it only appears when you hover your mouse over it? Selenium webdriver python;

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, hover

So what I am trying to do is to press the heartpulse emoji from the selection shown in the image, selenium can do this already by using it's xpath, but this only works if you hover your mouse over that region, as the preview for all the emojis disappears when you move your mouse. So would there be a way to select the heartpulse emoji without having to manually hover my mouse over it?

Code so far: `heartpulse = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/article/div/aside/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/button/span/img") heartpulse.click()`

Again, this only works when you hover your mouse above the region that shows the various emojis, otherwise it does nothing.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wccuq.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5T8G.jpg)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK2NB.png)

[Link](https://community.giffgaff.com/d/33277912-calling-inside-uk-why-deduct-my-money/3)

Comment: None of your images are showing up... please edit your question and fix them.

Comment: @JeffC Images have now been added, not to sure what happened to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you have to hover over that element first, then click on heart-pulse icon as following. Don't forget delays :)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


reactions_btns = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,'Reactions')]')

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(reactions_btns[0])
hover.perform()

heart_pulses = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@title="heartpulse"]')
heart_pulses[0].click()
```